# Best way to Enable/Disable CMenu items in real time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm working on a project using Visual C++ 6.0, and I need to be able to enable or disable certain menu items depending on the permissions assigned to the currently logged in user. This is the code I'm using:

```
// If the currently logged in user doesn't have permission to edit invoices
if (!((CMyApp *)AfxGetApp())->UserHasPermission(PERMISSION_EditInvoice))
{
    // Disable the Edit Menu
    pMain->EnableMenuItem(1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
}
else
{
    // Enable the Edit Menu
    pMain->EnableMenuItem(1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_ENABLED);
}
```

It does exactly what I want it to do, however I'm trying to find the best place to put it. If I put it in `OnInitialUpdate()`, I get the results I want, but only for the first invoice opened. If you open a second invoice without closing and re-opening the dialog, the code is not executed again. `OnUpdate()` isn't called when opening a different invoice, and the only other place I've found that works is `OnDraw()`, the problem with `OnDraw()` is that the menu item doesn't visually change state from Grayed out to Enabled or vice versa until you try to click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding to disable the `Edit Invoice` menu item, instead of the `Edit` menu itself. This proved much easier and cleaner, as it determines permission and enables or disables item every time the main `'Edit` menu is opened.

```
void CViewInvoiceView::OnUpdateEditEditinvoice(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) 
{
    // If the currently logged in user doesn't have permission to edit invoices
    if (!((CJ3App *)AfxGetApp())->UserHasPermission(PERMISSION_EditInvoice))
    {
        // Disable the Edit Menu
        pCmdUI->Enable(false);
    }
    else
    {
        // Enable the edit menu
        pCmdUI->Enable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must include this code in a procedure

void check_user_permission();

than you must call it when this events occur:

```
- OnInitialUpdate()
- new user login (if your software permits user login/logout during the same session)
- new invoice opened
```

Can it help?

Comment: Sort of. The problem wasn't that it wasn't being called every time the invoice changed, but that I couldn't get the GUI to update itself to show the new state of the menu without the user having to attempt to click it first.